# ios opengl es 2 object superposing faces bug

Tags: xcode5, opengl-es-2.0, blender

I'm trying to OpenGL es 2, I've a scene with an mesh loaded, it "work" but faces superposing bug.

[image]
[image]

Any idea to fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from image you have depth test disabled.

To draw opaque objects you need to enable depth test. Also backface culling will improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are having here is what we call z-fighting.
Precision in the ZBuffer is sometimes too small for polygons that are really too close.

Using Direct3D you could use Z-bias to fix this.
Using OpenGL, I believe it is called Polygon Offset.

Hope this helps find your problem!